# How to get GCM notification optional data with out click it? when app is in background

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

When receive a GCM notification in background, when user click the notification, it will link to my app and then I can get the data bundle in this GCM notification.

But is there any way to get the data in notification without click it? like, if the notification comes, user do not click the notification, he clicks the app instead and directly open the app. At this time, is that possible to get all the notification payload when user open the app?

Comment: yes, you can, in your broadcast reciever you can control enythings.

Comment: Can you give me any example or show me more detail? How can I get the data in my broadcast reciever? if the notification is received when app is in background? I know I can get it if app is in foreground or if user click the notification and open the app. But how to get is if user directly open the app without click notification?

Comment: Just to clarify things.. When your app is in background, if a notification from your server is received, you want it to automatically show your app to foreground?

Comment: no. I do not want it show my app to foreground, what I need is: if multiple notification comes, when I click one of the notification, I can get all data from all notifications. I do not want to click it one by one.

Comment: in another word, I want to get out all the data from all notifications without click it. Is there a way allow me to touch into gcm notification that saved in the notification tray without click it?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive GCM message, android call your BroadcastReceiver, even if your app is in background:

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        L.m("onReceive GCM called!");

        //Get your data
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        String tickerText = intent.getStringExtra("tickerText");
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        String dateTime = intent.getStringExtra("datetime");

        //Here, You can save your data in SQLite
        //For example: I need to save title, msg and dateTime
        DBGcmMessages dbGcmMessages = new DBGcmMessages(context);
        dbGcmMessages.insert(title, msg, dateTime);

        //Then, you can show notification or show nothing!!!
    }
}
```

and this is `DBGcmMessages` content:

```
public class DBGcmMessages extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "gcm_message_db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE = "login";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "_title";
    private static final String COLUMN_TEXT = "_text";
    private static final String COLUMN_DATE_TIME = "_date_time";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
            COLUMN_TITLE + " nvarchar(255)," +
            COLUMN_TEXT + " text," +
            COLUMN_DATE_TIME + " nvarchar(255));";

    public DBGcmMessages(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            L.m("Create table gcm messages successfully!");

        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {

            L.m(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {

            L.m("upgrade table gcm message executed!");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE + " IF EXISTS;");

            onCreate(db);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException exception) {

            L.m(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void insert(String title, String text, String dateTime) {

        try {

            if (title == null || text == null) return;

            this.mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

            //Insert
            String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(" +
                    COLUMN_TITLE + "," +
                    COLUMN_TEXT + "," +
                    COLUMN_DATE_TIME + ") VALUES (?,?,?);";

            SQLiteStatement statement = this.mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);

            statement.bindString(1, title);
            statement.bindString(2, text);
            statement.bindString(3, dateTime);

            statement.execute();

            L.m("Insert gcm message successfully!");
        }
        finally {

            if(this.mDatabase != null) this.mDatabase.close();
            this.close();
        }
    }

    public void delete(int id) {

        try {

            this.mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

            this.mDatabase.execSQL("Delete from " + TABLE + " where " + COLUMN_ID + "='" + id + "'");

            L.m("Delete gcm message successfully!");
        }
        finally {

            if(this.mDatabase != null) this.mDatabase.close();
            this.close();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<GCMMessage> getAll() {

        this.mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = null;

        try {

            result = this.mDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE + " order by " + COLUMN_ID + " desc", null);

            int rows = result.getCount();
            if (rows == 0) return null;

            ArrayList<GCMMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();

            result.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

                int id = result.getInt(0);
                String title = result.getString(1);
                String text = result.getString(2);
                String dateTime = result.getString(3);

                messages.add(new GCMMessage(id, title, text, dateTime));

                result.moveToNext();
            }

            L.m("Get all gcm message : " + rows);

            return messages;

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            return null;
        }
        finally {

            if(result != null) result.close();
            if(this.mDatabase != null) this.mDatabase.close();
            this.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work. GCM listener will not be called if app is in background. It will send the notification to android notification tray and it will start a intent when user click the notification.

Comment: As it turns out you do not know much about it.